# Angular2 - using a directive in <head>

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a custom image directive I want to use in my index.html to load the favicon

```
<head>    
   <link rel="shortcut icon" [my_directive]="path to image"/>
   ...
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

the problem is that main Angular component is bootstrapping into the *content* div and the directive in the head section is ignored.

Any advice on bootstrapping a component so that I can use it's directive in the html head?

**Update**

I created a Plunker with a simplified use case, where I created a directive that is rendered as expected under a component but ignored in the index.html, see http://plnkr.co/edit/zZoR0kiCm1szy7dlXtdk?p=preview

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives and all kinds of Angular2 template binding syntax can only be used within Angular2 component templates.

You can bootstrap a component on the `<head>` element but Angular purges the whole content of the element where a component is bootstrapped on.

Therefore there is no sane way of using directives on or in `<head>`

Comment: Disappointing that it was overlooked. Thanks for the response

Comment: I tried creating a directive whose selector is "html" and its template is "<ng-content>", and expected the <head> and <body> to be projected. But the content is still purged. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `<ng-content>` or `@Input()` is not supported on the root element.

Comment: Gunter is right. Just to add a workaround, you could create a service that dynamically adds/manipulates the link tag. See here [how to safely access head elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659205/adding-script-dynamically-to-head-in-angular/66765191#66765191). Bonus: The service even has quick methods for link elements.