# Adding script dynamically to <head> in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've checked some example that demonstrate how to add script with URL dynamically in Angular

But I want to add this kind of stuff to `<head>`

```
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
  n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
  document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

  fbq('init', '<FB_PIXEL_ID>');
  fbq('track', "PageView");
</script>
```

or

```
  <noscript>something</noscript>
```

or both.

Any ideas, examples?

Comment: Can't you add it in the `index.html`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding script script dinamicaly to <head> in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659175/adding-script-script-dinamicaly-to-head-in-angular)

Comment: @StPaulis no, I get it from a API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make an function, which gets the (first) head tag from the document and add an created script tag (with the code you specify in `innerHTML`) before the first child of the head tag:

```
export function addScriptsToHead() {
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

   
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.innerHTML = 'your code';

  head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the reference of an element using `getElementByTagName()` method by passing the tag name. After that you have to create a script variable then insert code to the variable using `innerHTML` attribute. Finally insert the script variable into head.

Try the following code,

```
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.innerHTML = 'your code';
  head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can allow yourself to install a new library, use the `HeadService` that comes with `@bespunky/angular-zen`. It provides a safe and strongly-typed access to the head element.

Your component / service would look something like this:

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { HeadService       } from '@bespunky/angular-zen/core';

 @Component({
     selector   : 'zen-head-service-demo',
     templateUrl: './head-service-demo.component.html',
     styleUrls  : ['./head-service-demo.component.css']
 })
 export class HeadServiceDemoComponent implements OnInit
 {
     constructor(private head: HeadService) { }

     ngOnInit()
     {
         this.head.addElement('script', /* config object or config function */);
     }
 }
```

[Live examples](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/Core%20Module/HeadService) | [Service docs](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/docs/zen/additional-documentation/coremodule/headservice.html) | [Service API](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/docs/zen/injectables/HeadService.html)

> ‍♂️ Remember to `npm install @bespunky/angular-zen` and import `CoreModule` from the `/core` package.

---

#### TLDR

The `HeadService` has other cool features like looking up elements by attributes, support for well known elements (e.g. scripts and styles), etc.

It's also testing-ready, meaning you can easily mock the document element or spy on it.

Answer (score -3):

here my example that i actually use in my project :

```
<head>
    <div *ngIf="dati">
        <title>{{dati.data.field_meta_tag.description}}</title>
    </div>
</head>
```

for do this you need to use rjxs operator and take the response to your api,in my example i use it only for the title now but you can use it for all.